# How could I add an md5 file to the tarball sdist creates?

Tags: python, setuptools

Either I'd like to create a new command as part of my `setup.py` file (`python setup.py manifest`), or extend the `sdist` command itself.

For distributions I'm doing, the "built" files that go into the `sdist` created tarball turn out to be static.  Having an md5 summary file distributed with the installed module would be handy way to check the module.

***Are their namespace elements in the sdist object such as the list of files that go into the tarball, or the name of the tarball that could help me with this?***

Something this is what I thought might make sense:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Command
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist

 ...

class my_sdist(sdist):
    # Get file list for the tarball
    flist = sdist. ???
    # Do the MD5
    os.system( ... )
    # Add the new MD5 File to the list
    sdist. ??? = flist + new file

    return sdist.run(self)

 ...

setup( ... , cmdclass = { 'sdist' : my_sdist }, ... )
```

Comment: "Having an md5 summary file distributed with the installed module" — sdists are not the *installed* format for Python packages.  Packages installed with any reasonably recent version of pip will be installed as wheels (built from the sdist if no wheel is available), which contain `RECORD` files listing the SHA 256 hashes of all other files in the wheel.

Comment: @jwodder Unfortunately, until I can figure out how (read as "be bothered") to deal with configuration files that have to be installed in `/etc/{init.d,logrotate.d,cron.hourly}` I'm stuck with a non-wheel distribution (using the `--no-binary` option).  That said, does the `RECORD` file (for a wheels install) get installed?

Comment: Yes, the `RECORD` file is placed in a `*.dist-info` directory next to the installed Python code along with the rest of the wheel metadata.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your md5 checksums file before `setup.py sdist` (via perhaps `make`) and then including it with `MANIFEST.in`?

#### `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include README.rst LICENSE ... CHECKSUM
```

#### `Makefile`

```
checksum:
    find . -name CHECKSUM -prune -o -type f -exec md5sum '{}' >CHECKSUM \;

package: checksum
    python setup.py sdist
```

#### Usage

```
$ make package
```

Calculates `md5` checksums for all the files in `.` recursively (except for the file `CHECKSUM`) and updates the `CHECKSUM` file. Then, it calls `setup.py sdist` which will include the updated checksums file in the package.

Comment: Yeah ... but from project to project the file list that is used to generate the `CHECKSUM` file can vary.  Instead of the `find . -name ...` command, I could use a file list, but I'd be maintaining two file lists: one for the Makefile and another for setuptools.  I'd think I'd really rather have it in `setup.py`.

Comment: I see. You could calculate checksums only for files included in the package (tar.gz), after packaging, and then add it to that package; or include checksums only for files in staging dir; or maybe even just use files from `git ls-files`...

Comment: I think you appreciate why I was hoping to do it in the manner I suggested now.  If I were relying solely on something to do with git (`git ls-files`) then the git hash would be sufficient.